# Column with mutiples status - automatic today's date when status is changed to "completed"

Tags: list, sharepoint, formula, power-automate

I have a Microsoft List with a column named "Status" which is a column type with multiples choices.
I want the user to have today's date when he chose a certain choice from the column "Status".
For instance, when the status is "completed", then the column "Date of completion" shall display automatically today's date.

What would be the formula, and should it be entered in the column "Date of completion" parameter > column validation in the field "formula" ?
Or do I need to use power automate ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

<s>I would use [column formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4rRg.png) for this.</s>. I would use Power Automate for this.

Create a flow like below.

1. Use the When an item is created or modified trigger action.
2. In the Settings add a trigger expression like below (again change it to use the internal column names). 
   *That expression checks if the Status field value is Completed and if the Date of Completion field is still empty.*

   @and(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Status/Value'], 'Completed'), empty(triggerOutputs()?['body/Dateofcompletion']))
3. In the Update Item use UtcNow for the Date of Completion field

   utcNow()

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried but it is not displaying anything
Also I think the column type should be "Date and hour" 
Whereas my column "Status" is a column type "Choices"

Comment: The Status column is also a choice field in my setup (with the ability to select multiple options). The Date of Completion is Single line of text type. 

Keep in mind that the [$Status] part of the formula refers to the internal name of the column. Double check if that name is different in your setup.

Also make sure the casing of the 'Completed' value is the same. In my choice label it was written as Completed, if it is lower case in your setup do change that to 'completed'.

Comment: I rechecked the column and label name and removed special characters such as "é", but it is still not display anything in my Date column :(

Comment: Did you check it in the list settings? Sometimes internal column names have unicode characters, https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html

Comment: indeed the internal name was different, thanks to the tutorial Its now working
But the date is moving to real time, I need the date to be fixed in time. Let's say the user finish a task and put the "completed" status, I need to know that it was at 5:02PM 09/06/22 for history matter. If the date keeps moving to real time I dont see the point.

Another question, do you know if its possible to use a Yes/No column to do the same trick as with a choice ? For instance, my Yes/no column could display the date in my Date of publication column IF the user tick the box "Yes".

Comment: You are right, let me have another look at the formula design again. I might be able to fix that formula with a check for empty and an appendTo function.

Comment: I am having second thoughts about my approach. The value is only shown on the column, not actually set as a value. So, I will edit my answer with a different approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Atm I don't have access to Power Automate but as soon as I can get it, i'll Try your solution and tell you if it works

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help :)